# What happens when you close a payment channel on tumblebit?

Tags: tumblebit

When you close a payment channel using tumblebit, what happens?
Is the channel that you close always between you and only one other?
Is the channel between you and any number of accounts/addresses?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All the parties who wish to pay have at least one payment channel to the Tumbler (i.e. the payment hub), all parties that wish to accept payments have a payment channel from the Tumbler to them. Thus, each payment channel is either from the user to the Tumbler or from the Tumbler to the user.